# Change the description of the forgot password page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, passwords, shortcode

I am having a problem with a template page that I created. I import the do_shortcode (‘[reset_password]’); in my template page.

I would like to change the description sentence »
Please enter your username or email address. You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password. ".

However I can not find anything on the web, surely content to be entered in the functions.php ...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit wp-login.php and replace the text

You can find the text on line number 843

Comment: Not good idea when WordPress doing a update.